# How can I change the shader of an object when that object is in proximity with another object or Empty?

Tags: texturing, shaders, geometry-nodes

I would like to have an empty object that I can animate on an array and change the shader of the instance which is currently in proximity with my empty.
Is it possible with geometry nodes?

---

I managed to do this, but I can get the instace to color fully. I would like just to switch color on the entire instance, is this possible? I've tried to compare the distance to a threshold.
[image]

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. Best with providing blend file. And yes, it is possible

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maniplate the shader you have to use shader nodes, not geometry. You can calculate the two object's distance with Texture Coordinate nodes (Input>>Texture Coordinate) and a Vector Math node (Converter>>Vector Math>>Distance). Then you can adjust the output with a Math node (Converter>>Math>>Multiply OR Divide). Then its output can drive any "Fac" input like ColorRamp or Mix Shader.
[image]

Comment: I can get the instace to color fully. I would like just to switch color on the entire instance, is this possible? I've tried to compare the distance to a threshold. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfhvH.png